# How to generate swagger for my API where one property of return type can be polymorphic?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, openapi

I am trying to generate Swagger JSON for my web api which is developed in c# using Swashbuckle. There is a case where one object property of my return type can be polymorphic based on a string/enum value in containing object (discriminator). When I went through swagger docs and other online helps, it is found we can support polymorphism based on a property in same object but not containing object. Below is example of my api response. Is this scenario supported in OpenAPI specification? I read about OneOf property which is introduced in Swagger 3.0 and wondering is this the solution I should use? if so, can we use OneOf with a discriminator?

In below sample code, based on enum DeviceType, DeviceProperties can be either ABCDeviceProperties or XYZDeviceProperties. Is it possible to generate swagger for api which returns or accepts "Device"?

```
    public enum DeviceType {ABC, XYZ }
    public class Device
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public DeviceType Type { get; set; }
        public DeviceProperties Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceProperties
    {
        public string MemorySize { get; set; }
    }

    public class ABCDeviceProperties : DeviceProperties
    {
        public string Abc { get; set; }
    }

    public class XYZDeviceProperties : DeviceProperties
    {
        public string Xyz { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to have such a dependency in the first place? Why not simply remove the DeviceType from the interface  and derive it based on DeviceProperties? The client will still set the DeviceProperties based on a discriminator.

Comment: Hi @IvayloStoev, My assumption was that it is good to have a field (DeviceType) which user can use to specify what are values can be expected in "DeviceProperties". If this is not a supported/standard document, I can change it they way you told. But I was wondering if OneOf introduced in Swagger 3.0 is to support this scenario.

Comment: Not really. Check this out: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#oneof

Comment: Thanks @IvayloStoev. I think I will change it the way you suggested